# Browser loading finished before getting all the data from ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

I have an issue with data loading. I'm creating a dashboard with many Ajax calls. When I refresh the web page sometimes it works fine. But sometimes it rendered without some ajax calls ( means some data are missing). But I, again and again, reload the page it works fine.

**Is there any method to fix this problem from JavaScript side or else.** I want to do is showing loading screen until all data loaded into the browser.

Comment: make your ajax call with promises and wait for resolve for more check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the cache. I suggest you set the HTTP header "Last-Modified" on the HTTP response to ensure the browser refreshes the cache when there is newer data than that which is located in the cache.